# Collect data about the user navigation in my website

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-analysis, analytics

I would like to know if there is any library to start collecting information for a website about:

- Time in page per user
- Most common pages visited per user
- Most visited pages
- Less visited pages
- Similar stuff

I can do this manually, but it would be less time consuming it there is any library (I have the site in python/flask) or software ready to start collecting all this information directly to a database about the GET requests for each user.

My intention is to use this type of data to show a more granular information accordingly the user behavior (ok, this is the second step not relevant here).

I don't have interest in google analytics since I want to work this data in "real time".

Answer (score 1):

Install [Inspectlet](https://www.inspectlet.com) on your website. It will do most of the work you described in your question. You can even view the video recording where the user had clicked or hovered the cursor

Comment: I am not looking for a service, but  a library or self hosted tool.